# cgroups v2 cpuset doesn't take an effect without process restart

Tags: linux, scheduling, cgroups

I'm trying to isolate some CPU cores for latency-sensitive processes using the cpuset controller in cgroup v2.

I created a group `lowlatency`:

```
mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/lowlatency
```

and restricted it to use only `1-7,9-15` CPUs:

```
echo "1-7,9-15" > /sys/fs/cgroup/lowlatency/cpuset.cpus
```

Also, I made this group as a `root` of a new cpuset partition:

```
echo "root" > /sys/fs/cgroup/lowlatency/cpuset.cpus.partition
```

Finally, the root group no more uses isolated CPUs `1-7,9-15`:

```
cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset.cpus.effective
0,8
```

The problem is that processes in root subgroups still use the wrong CPUs.

[image]

The CPU affinity mask is correct:

[image]

After killing and restarting, they are placed on the right CPUs (0 and 8).
Is it a bug in cgroups? Can I move these processes to a new cpuset without restarting?

I tried to remove the lowlatency group with `cpuset.cpus.partition=root` and do `taskset -cp 4 1079` manually, and it works without any restart:

[image]

Comment: When were the problematic PID started, before or after you setup the cgroup? Did you try putting the PIDs into the `tasks` file to move them into a cgroup?

Comment: @thrig Hi. All "ungrouped" processes are in the root group (`/sys/fs/cgroup/`) by default. I see their PIDs in `/sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.procs` file. These processes were started before I set up `cpuset partition`. When I restarted these processes, they were placed on the right CPUs.

Comment: It looks like a kernel bug that it doesn't update column 39, CPU number last executed on, of /proc/[pid]/stat after writing cpuset.cpus. Try `perf  sched record` then `perf sched timehist`  to see if it shows the expected CPUs.

Related bug:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1618688